# docker image size getting doubled

Tags: docker

I have a question about docker. If I do

```
docker build -t my_image .
(after a few updates) 
docker build -t my_image .
```

Then, the size of my_image is not changed, when I check with 'docker images'.

However, if I do

```
docker build -t my_image .
docker save -o my_image.tar my_image
(after a few updates) 
docker build -t my_image .
```

then, the size of my image is doubled. It looks like a new image contains both the old and the new one.

Does anybody know why this happens, and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you look in the folder where you created the image - it should contain the *my_image.tar* file. Then look in your Dockerfile, and see if you also add all things from the folder to the image - since if so I guess the image adds the new .tar to itself every time (and thus is doubled in size, containing a Matryoshka doll of tar-ed images).

Comment: You should show your Dockerfile for a more detailed solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `save -o` command should output a *.tar* file in your directory.

If you in your *Dockerfile* has something like `ADD . /app` in it, this saved image will also get added, and the image size be doubled because of it.

What you could do is make sure that you do not add the saved *my_image.tar* when building the image, either by adding some more selection as to what is included in the image, or by saving the .tar somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem!

Comment: adding a line to ignore the .tar in a .dockerignore file should also do the trick